# (Beginner)Python functions Codeacademy

Tags: python

I'm just learning to program on Codeacademy. I have an assignment, but cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.

First I need to define a function that returns the cube of a value.  Then I should define a second function that checks if a number is divisible by 3. If it is I need to return it, otherwise I need to return `False`.

heres the code:

```
def cube(c):
    return c**3

def by_three(b):
    if b % 3 == 0:
         cube(b)
         return b
    else:
         return False
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not catching the return value of the function `cube`. Do `b = cube(b)`. Or better yet, do `return cube(b)`.

```
def cube(c):
    return c**3

def by_three(b):
    if b % 3 == 0:
         b = cube(b)
         return b  # Or simply return cube(b) and remove `b = cube(b)`
    else:
         return False
```

When you call the `cube` function with the argument `b`, it returns the cube of the passed argument, you need to store it in a variable and return that to the user, in your current code, you are neglecting the returned value.

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick, ill make a mental note to always store the new value in a variable

Comment: @LtC : No need to do that. Just `return cube(b)` would have worked too and is maybe a little bit more readable. Glad I was of help though. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this answer might also work:

```
    def cube(b,c):
        b = c ** 3
        if b % 3 == 0:
            return b
        else:
            return False
        return b
```

I know that might be a little redundant but I think that might be another way of doing what you're trying to do. What Sukrit did I think is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I have finished Codecdemy and this is my code.

```
def cube(n):
    return n ** 3
def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
       return cube(number)
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a lightweight solution I just developed, should work :)**

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3

def by_three(number):
    if number % 3 == 0:
        return cube(number)
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cube(num):
    return n ** 3

def by_three(value):
    if value % 3 == 0:
        return cube(value)
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

try calling the same letter for each. Instead of using 'c' and 'b', just use 'c'

```
def cube(c):
    return c**3
def by_three(c):
    if c % 3 ==0:
        return cube(c)
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: changing the variable name isn't the solution, its the fact that you added "return" in front of cube, so you are returning the return value of cube.  The OP's code was returning an unmodified variable 'b'

Comment: Lastly, i do not believe this provides a correct solution for def by_three, it should just return the var, and not call the function.